# How set Chrome Notication Permission to default using Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Doing test in rspec and have this settings for capybara.

```
Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.server = :puma, {Silent: true}
  config.enable_aria_role = true
  config.enable_aria_label = true
  config.default_max_wait_time = 10
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include ActionView::RecordIdentifier, type: :system
  config.before(type: :system) { driven_by :selenium, using: :headless_chrome, screen_size: [1400, 1400] }  
end
```

[image: Default Permission]

Is there an option to set the browser's notification settings to default?